# How to create MP4 file when using AR Drone 2.0 c# API

Tags: c#, api, mp4, ar.drone

I have tried to instal and use https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone to control my AR Drone 2.0. It perform well. However, when I use it to record video, it shows a file name .ardrone which cannot be read through other player unless I use the API replay function. I tried to change the file name into .mp4 rather than .ardrone inside the code but it still not working. Any method I can generate a MP4 file?

Super thanks!

Comment: Maybe post the code you use to record video?